# Ember select view not working with latest version of ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a working example of Ember select view one using ember version ember-0.9.5.js

and the same example does not work with latest version of Ember

http://jsfiddle.net/k9Gp9/

### Any help to make the second example work is really appreciated

Added later..... after the question was answered...

I have created another sample with the selection list. I am trying to follow the MVC pattern where the Controller is responsible for the populating the model and binding it to the view.

http://jsfiddle.net/C7eY5/

I cannot get the select or the selection value to work correctly. The only difference between the earlier example is the controller extends from Em.Controller and the name of the bound property is not the default "content".

Answer (score 1):

That second fiddle still includes 0.9.5 -- I [updated it](http://jsfiddle.net/pauldechov/k9Gp9/1/) to include [ember-1.0.pre.js](https://github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-1.0.pre.js) and [handlebars](https://github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.0.beta.6.js) (which is required by but no longer bundled with ember) and now it works just as the first example did.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have updated the question with another request

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code in sample 2.

[Here is the link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C7eY5/6/)

```
{{view Ember.Select
     contentBinding="rvalues"
     selectionBinding="rvalue"
     optionLabelPath="content.name"
     optionValuePath="content.value"
     prompt="Pick a RValue:"
     id="emberEnhanced"}}
```